# .xlsx files abort the git restore command and produce an index.lock file

Tags: git, xlsx, restore

After `git clone <url>`, a lot of files are automatically deleted and present in staged area. I did `git reset` to bring all to unstaged area. Then I executed `git restore .`. In this step, files start to get restored but the operation is aborted when a `.xlsx` file has to be restored. After that no other file gets restored.

Comment: Does git give any error message or whatnot?

Comment: No. No error msg.

Answer (score 0):

I think Excel opens the files with locks, make sure you close the application (or check task manager for hung processes that might be locking it)